# Terminal velocity for rotating system

Tags: rotational-dynamics

Suppose we have a small bob/ball attached via rigid rod to a pivot in a viscous medium and then rotated by a constant torque, will the system finally(after considerable time) rotate with constant velocity, or will the viscous torque not be able to completely cancel out the applied torque and the system will be accelerated forever ?

If the viscous torque will cancel out the torque, is there a method to calcupate this viscous torque ? As well as the terminal angular velocity.

Also, if we attach the pivot to a dynamo, and the same constant torque is applied on the system, will it still rotate with the same terminal angular velocity ?

Comment: What's the mathematical model for viscous torque? Does its magnitude increase with increasing speed? If so, this can be used to answer your first question. If you're unfamiliar with these ideas, take a look at the condition for linear terminal velocity.

Comment: I am familiar with ideas, but I am clueless about the matematical models or calculations therein.